# How to connect to a serverside process on Ubuntu running in a VM?

Tags: server, networking, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 in VirtualBox, on Windows 7. I'm trying to setup a serverside process like Apache on it. How do I configure VirtualBox to allow access to the Ubuntu server process from other computers on the network?

1. I can access the internet from Ubuntu.
2. The Windows 7 computer is on a WiFi network using DHCP.
3. The WiFi network has a dynamic IP with the network provider.

This is my current configuration:

[image: network]

Answer (score 1):

In your current network configuration the guest machine is not accessible by other devices on your network because it is using NAT.
Shut it down and set it to be *Bridged* instead of NAT. Once you start the machine again it will connect to the network and get its own IP address that others on the network can access to.

Comment: I tried setting "Bridged adapter" and restarting. ifconfig command displays a ip address for the guest machine as 10.210.x.x, but I can not connect to the guest vm from my host machine through putty. What could be wrong?